# this would be the normal way of expressing it

Tags: modal-verbs

How would you suggest a sentence to someone?

Student: I wrote this sentence: XYZ. Is my sentence natural?

a) Teacher: It's OK but this **would be** the normal way of expressing it: ABC.

b) Teacher: It's OK but this **will be** the normal way of expressing it: ABC.

c) Teacher: It's OK but this  **is** the normal way of expressing it: ABC.

Are they all correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a) Teacher: It's OK but this **would be** the normal way of expressing it: ABC.

This is fine, although it might be clearer to say: *It's OK, but the normal way of expressing it would be: ABC.*

> b) Teacher: It's OK but this **will be** the normal way of expressing it: ABC.

This sounds wrong.

> c) Teacher: It's OK but this **is** the normal way of expressing it: ABC.

This is fine, although it might be clearer to say: *It's OK, but the normal way of expressing it is: ABC.*

Comment: Also, when suggesting a particular sentence to someone, people often say: *You **would** say: ABC*. I think "you **will** say: ABC" would sound wrong here. Am I right?

Comment: You are right, @Mr.X